# Display entries of nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dict that looks like this:

```
17733124060: {'PhoneOwner': u'Bob', 'Frequency': 0}, 
18444320737: {'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah', 'Frequency': 1}, 
18444320742: {'PhoneOwner': u'Jane', 'Frequency': 0}
```

I want to be able to run a query that presents back the key 17733124060 and PhoneOwner Bob if the frequency is 0.

So far I have:

```
for phoneNumber, PhoneOwner, Frequency in dict.iteritems():
    if Frequency == 0:
    print phoneNumber + PhoneOwner
```

But when I run this, I get an error:

```
for phoneNumber, PhoneOwner, Frequency in phoneNumberDictionary.iteritems():
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

What am I missing where?

Comment: Note that you might run into another error when trying to concatenate phoneNumber with PhoneOwner, since you cannot contatenate int with str. So you need to either cast to a string (`str(phoneNumber + [...])`), or let the print function do it by giving the values as different arguments: `print phoneNumber, PhoneOwner` will print both values separated by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `for phoneNumber, PhoneOwner, Frequency in dict.iteritems():`

You are trying to unpack two values (`dict.itertimes()` returns 2-tuples) into 3 variables. Instead you should first iterate over the outer dict, then evaluate the nested dict:

```
for phoneNumber, inner_dict in phonenumbers.iteritems():
    if inner_dict['Frequency'] == 0:
        print str(phoneNumber) + inner_dict['PhoneOwner']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to first build a list of matching entries and then print them as follows:

```
my_dict = {
    17733124060: {'PhoneOwner': u'Bob', 'Frequency': 0}, 
    18444320737: {'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah', 'Frequency': 1}, 
    18444320742: {'PhoneOwner': u'Jane', 'Frequency': 0}}

zero_freq = [(k, v['PhoneOwner']) for k, v in my_dict.items() if v['Frequency'] == 0]

for number, owner in zero_freq:
    print number, owner
```

This would display the following:

```
17733124060 Bob
18444320742 Jane
```

Also, just in case, don't name your dictionary `dict` as this a builtin Python function.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using the built-in method, [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), where you filter your dictionary according to your condition (`sub_d[Frequency]==0`), this way:

```
>>> d
{17733124060L: {'Frequency': 0, 'PhoneOwner': u'Bob'}, 18444320742L: {'Frequency': 0, 'PhoneOwner': u'Jane'}, 18444320737L: {'Frequency': 1, 'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah'}}
>>> for i in filter(lambda s:d[s]['Frequency']==0, d):
    print '%d %s' % (i, d[i]['PhoneOwner'])


17733124060 Bob
18444320742 Jane
```